# Understanding Concurrent pre clean and card tables

Tags: java, garbage-collection

So far I have understod that card tables are used to mark any objects from the tenured region that references to the young generation as dirty in case any references have been modified.
But reading in [link](https://programmer.group/understanding-the-preclean-phase-of-cms-recycler.html), and especially the figure under the section 'What pre clean did', it seems like the card table also stores young objects with references to the old generation. Is that correct? Does a card table store both way references?

Comment: Objects are stored in the *heap memory* and that’s what you see in the picture, a schematic of the heap memory, including the Young Generation and the Old Generation, the latter consisting of *cards*. The picture doesn’t show what the card table stores, aside from the one dirty flag.